# Unexpected result of copying multiple regex matches to clipboard

Tags: regex, emeditor

I have a file that contains the following text:

```
<div class="a">
a
b
c
d
</div>
<div class="b">

</div>
<div class="a">
e
f
g
h
</div>
```

I go to `Search > Find...`, check `Regular Expressions`, then go to `Advanced...`, check the `Regular Expression “.” Can Match Newline Characters` option and set the number 12 as the value for `Additional Lines to Search for Regular Expressions`. Then I type

```
<div class="a".*?</div>
```

as the regular expression to match, click the `Select All` button (in the `Find` panel) and obtain two fragments of selected text. Then I click `Edit > Copy`. But when I create a new text file (in Emeditor) and paste the copied data in there, the result is

```
<div class="a">
a
b
c
d
<
<div class="a">
e
f
g
h
<
```

instead of the expected

```
<div class="a">
a
b
c
d
</div>
<div class="a">
e
f
g
h
</div>
```

What is the reason of this behavior and how to make Emeditor produce the expected result?

Comment: Seems the `/` messes up the regex, try to escape it: `\/`.

Comment: @PoulBak: but the selected fragments are exactly as I expect them to be. Why doesn't the program copy them in their entirety?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with EmEditor Version 21.9.909. Which version of EmEditor are you using?

Comment: @Yutaka: 21.9.1.0 (64-bit) portable, but I have observed this issue in various versions of Emeditor. I have edited the question to add details.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the issue with v21.9.1. Please write all the options you set or reset in the `Find` and `Advanced` dialog boxes. Are you using `Boost.Regex` or `Onigmo`? Were the two selections correct (including `/div>`) before you select `Edit` - `Copy`? Please try switching to another document tab or an app and come back to this document tab to see if the selections change? Please try pasting the Clipboard to `Notepad`. Please let me know what you find.

Comment: @Yutaka: Thank you very much for your attention. Yesterday the issue disappeared (I did not change any options), and the results were all correct. This is really, really weird. I have no idea what is going on in my system. Maybe the OS lacks some proper drivers (such as the chipset driver for the motherboard)? [1/4]

Comment: @Yutaka: Regarding your question: “Were the two selections correct (including `/div>`) before you select `Edit` - `Copy`?” —  yes, all the selections were correct, the problem manifested itself after I copied them, then pasted into a document. The issue was definitely not my illusion: I have conducted many tests, and the program always refused to copy-paste all selected fragments in their entirety: namely, all parts after `.*?` were incomplete. [2/4]

Comment: @Yutaka: Regarding your suggestion: “Please try pasting the Clipboard to Notepad” — yes, I should have pasted the clipboard to a document in another application to test whether the data was correct, but I forgot to do this. So it is not clear whether the issue was in Copy or Paste operation... [3/4]

Comment: @Yutaka: Regarding my statement: “I have observed this issue in various versions of EmEditor” — it is incorrect. This particular issue has been observed only in version 21.9.1 (64-bit) portable, for a single day (the day before yesterday). [4/4]